# iPhone Development - Is Pin Annotation in a viewable Map Region

Tags: iphone, annotations, mapkit, mkmapview, region

How can i check if a pin is in viewable region of the map (MKMapView)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pin is a `MKPinAnnotationView`, it extends from `MKAnnotationView` and has a property `annotation` (that conforms to the protocol `MKAnnotation`). Such annotation has itself another property `coordinate`.

Just compare the latitude / longitude of such coordinate to the region of your map.

something like this should do it :

`double minLong = myMap.region.center.longitude - myMap.region.span.longitudeDelta/2.0;
double maxLong = myMap.region.center.longitude + myMap.region.span.longitudeDelta/2.0;
double minLat = myMap.region.center.latitude - myMap.region.span.latitudeDelta/2.0;
double maxLat = myMap.region.center.latitude + myMap.region.span.latitudeDelta/2.0;`

BOOL isPinInRegion = myPinCoordinates.longitude>=minLong && myPinCoordinates.longitude<=maxLong && myPinCoordinates.latitude>=minLat && myPinCoordinates.latitude<=maxLat;