# Best practice to display POI in iPhone's MapKit?

Tags: iphone, search, annotations, mapkit

Assuming I have a database of POI with their respective coordinates (longitude & latitude). What would be the "standard" way to display the POI as annotations around the user's current location? To elaborate:

- Given a zoom level, I guess I have to search through the database for all POI whose distance to the current location < a certain threshold, then create annotations for them. Or is there any smarter way?
- If the user zooms in/out, moves the map... I will need to redo the whole thing again?
- It seems that MapKit has a mechanism to cache/reuse annotations. Should I create a lot of them right away and let MapKit decides what to render when the visible region changes? I guess this would make the transition smoother, but also consumes more memory. What is your experience with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, relying on the distance between the current location and the POIs is not the right approach : evaluating distances takes time, you'd better just rely on the region displayed by your map (property `region`) and check which of your POIs are contained in this region.

When zooming in / out, the region changes, so you may have to redo the same.

See my answer here : 
[MKMapView loading all annotation views at once (including those that are outside the current rect)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262742/mkmapview-loading-all-annotation-views-at-once-including-those-that-are-outside/2536773#2536773)

This guy is trying to use the caching of annotations and my answer may help you in your case.

To check if your POI is the displayed region, I posted a piece of code that may help here :
[iPhone Development - Is Pin Annotation in a viewable Map Region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591494/iphone-development-is-pin-annotation-in-a-viewable-map-region/2592400#2592400)